# How to disable GSSAPI authentication using PuTTY Plink?

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I'm using `plink.exe` (from PuTTY) to run shell commands over SSH. Trying to authenticate via GSSAPI makes it slow ("freezes" ~ 7 sec while trying). Therefore I want to disable GGSSAPI authentication.

Under PuTTY I can disable GSSAPI authentication and everything is fine (because I don't want to authenticate via GSSAPI).

How to disable GSSAPI authentication using `plink.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no command-line switch in Plink/PuTTY to disable GSSAPI.

All you can do is to configure a stored session in PuTTY GUI with GSSAPI disabled and use it in Plink using [`-load` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-load).

```
plink -load "my session with disabled gssapi"
```

---

You can combine that with other command-line options. So you can create a stored session that only disables GSSAPI:

```
plink -load "disable gssapi" username@hostname
```